# Linq to SQL Case WHEN in VB.NET?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, t-sql

How do I do a Case WHEN in Linq to SQL (vb.net please).

In SQL it would be like this:

```
SELECT 
CASE
  WHEN condition THEN trueresult
  [...n]
[ELSE elseresult]
END
```

How would I do this in Linq to SQL?

Comment: The accepted answer is incorrect, as it does not match the language specified in the question title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check This Out

```
var data = from d in db.tb select new {

 CaseResult = (

 d.Col1 == “Case1” ? "Case 1 Rised" :

 d.Col1 == “Case2” ? "Case 2 Rised" :

 "Unknown Case")

 };
```

Please Note that [ ? Symbol = then] , [ : Symbol = Or].

Comment: That won't work in VB.NET.  Need to use If(cond, true, false)

Answer (score 11):

```
var data = from d in db.tb select new {

CaseResult = If (d.Col1 = “Case1”, "Case 1 Rised", If (d.Col1 = “Case2”, "Case 2 Rised", "Unknown Case"))

};
```

Comment: This answer is much better considering the original question specifically requested VB and the accepted C# syntax is quite different.  Considering -1 on accepted answer...

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this but you may be able to do something like:

```
Dim query = From tbl In db.Table _
            Select result =_
                If(tbl.Col1 < tbl.Col2,"Less than",_
                    If(tbl.Col1 = tbl.Col2,"Equal to","Greater than"))
```

You would just need to keep nesting the If functions to handle all of your cases.

You can find more examples of various queries at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386913.aspx

Comment: Thanks!  I guess this will have to do.